# Fullscreen GLFW window disappears when focus is lost

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw

I am creating an OpenGL window like this:

```
auto mode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitor);
mWindowWidth = mode->width;
mWindowHeight = mode->height;

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RED_BITS, mode->redBits);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_GREEN_BITS, mode->greenBits);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_BLUE_BITS, mode->blueBits);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_REFRESH_RATE, mode->refreshRate);

mWindow = glfwCreateWindow(mWindowWidth, mWindowHeight, "Test", monitor, NULL);
```

This works fine except for one major flaw:
When I focus another window (even if that's on a different monitor!) the GLFW window disappears in the background.

How can I create a (fullscreen) GLFW window that always stays on top on a given monitor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for GLFW is available here http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_windowed_full_screen

From the above link

#### Section : Window related hints

`GLFW_AUTO_ICONIFY` specifies whether the full screen window will automatically iconify and restore the previous video mode on input focus loss. This hint is ignored for windowed mode windows.

#### Default Value

`GLFW_TRUE`

#### Accepted Values

`GLFW_TRUE or GLFW_FALSE`

Set it to `GLFW_FALSE`

That is

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_AUTO_ICONFIY, GLFW_FALSE);
```

Note that `GLFW_TRUE` and `GLFW_FALSE` are and will always be just `1` and `0`.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that automatic minimization on focus loss is controlled by [`GLFW_AUTO_ICONIFY`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.2/window_guide.html#window_hints) hint, which is enabled by default.

> `GLFW_AUTO_ICONIFY` specifies whether the full screen window will automatically iconify and restore the previous video mode on input focus loss.
>   This hint is ignored for windowed mode windows.

It can be disabled with:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_AUTO_ICONIFY, 0);
```

Comment: I'd go for this answer as well